# Why wouldnt Mysql use index on the Primary query in a nested query

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5, subquery

I have two tables: `search_criteria` and `pricing`.

There is an index on `search_id` column  in `search_criteria` table and on `pricing_id` column in `pricing` table.

But running this nested query does not use index on `search_criteria` table.

```
explain 
select *  
from  search_criteria USE INDEX (idx_search_id) 
where  search_id in 
    (select search_id 
    from pricing
     where pricing_id = '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed');


+----+--------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table               | type | possible_keys                | key            | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | search_criteria | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  | 19582252 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pricing      | ref  | idx_pricing_id,idx_search_id | idx_pricing_id | 36      | const |        1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

If I use this table without the nested query it uses the index

```
explain extended select *  from  search_criteria where  search_id in ('36afabcc-e896-48b6-ad0f-c683845d4a4f')

+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | search_criteria | ref  | idx_search_id | idx_search_id | 103     | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
```

Why is this happening ?

MYSQL VARIABLES

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.1.8                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.5.16-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | linux2.6                     |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

After Jynus  reply, I have modified the question.

Executed Query :

```
explain 
  select s_c.*  
  from search_criteria s_c USE INDEX (idx_search_id) 
  JOIN pricing p USING (search_id)
  WHERE p.pricing_id = '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed';



    ----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key            | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | idx_pricing_id,idx_search_id | idx_pricing_id | 36      | const |        1 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s_c   | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  | 19663904 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

Show create sql of search_criteria;

```
CREATE TABLE `search_criteria` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `search_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `origin` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `dest` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `adults` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `children` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `infants` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `trip_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `flight_type` enum('INT','DOM') DEFAULT NULL,
 `depart_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `arrival_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `idx_search_id` (`search_id`),
 KEY `idx_created` (`created_on`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=288339047 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


 CREATE TABLE `pricing` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pricing_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `search_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `supplier_codes` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_pricing_id` (`pricing_id`),
   KEY `idx_created_on` (`created_on`),
   KEY `idx_search_id` (`search_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9264209 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: yes they are the same type varchar(100)

Comment: I've got the same quirk in my query - rather than using the list of IDs I'm generating in my sub-query to utilise the index, it just does a full table scan. However, it just occurred to me that it might be deciding this based on the fact that the sub-query could be returning 100s of IDs, and then it might actually be more efficient to do a table scan, rather than looking up each individual ID in the index.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to execute a [semijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29). This is a very well know issue with the MySQL optimizer before MySQL 5.6. The only way MySQL knows how to execute it is to perform a full table scan on the left table and execute the inner query once per row, thus it is unable to use the index.

You have several alternatives:

- Migrate to 5.6 (or MariaDB 5.5): it will be optimized correctly (I think in this case, converted to a JOIN transparently)
- Rewrite the query as a scalar subquery (**this only works if you expect to receive only one value, that is, pricing_id is unique**):

  ```
  explain 
  select *  
  from search_criteria USE INDEX (idx_search_id) 
  where search_id = 
    (select search_id 
     from pricing
     where pricing_id = '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed');
  ```
- Rewrite the query as a JOIN. This only works in some semijoins (those where you will not match more than one row at a time), but I think this is the case for you:

  ```
  explain 
  select s_c.*  
  from search_criteria s_c USE INDEX (idx_search_id) 
  JOIN pricing p USING (search_id)
  WHERE p.pricing_id = '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed';
  ```

By the way, once you have changed the query, you will not need the `USE INDEX`.

Comment: Another option is `EXISTS` subquery. And I think *"(this only works if you expect to receive only one value, that is, search_id is unique)"* should be: "this only works if you expect to receive only one value, that is, **pricing_id** is unique)"

Comment: @ypercube yes, thank you, I was editing it while you commented it.

Comment: I will have multiple rows in the subquery result so how will that work ? Also I tried explain select * from
search_criteria inner join pricing on
search_criteria.search_id = pricing.search_id 
where pricing.pricing_id =  '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed' 
 but its not working.

Comment: @ypercube also third query was wrong, I rewrote it

Comment: @tarnisharma Can you explain why this didn't work? `EXPLAIN SELECT s_c.* FROM search_criteria s_c JOIN pricing p ON s_c.search_id = p.search_id WHERE p.pricing_id = '009330be-d041-444f-a624-ca652f3f61ed'` Did you get an error? if not, what was the output?

Comment: Its again not indexing on search_criteria

|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | idx_pricing_id,idx_search_id | idx_pricing_id | 36      | const |        1 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s_c   | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  | 19663904 | Using where; Using join buffer |

Comment: @tarnisharma the query actually has solved the `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` problem, please edit the question with the formatted output of the new explain and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of both tables for further work. You may just need an index on `pricing (pricing_id, search_id)` and another on `search_criteria (search_id)`. You can add `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, but this doesn't seem like a good idea right now.

Comment: @Jynus : I have modified the question. Please check

Answer (score 6):

The reason why the index on `search_id` is not even considered is because the two tables - and therefore the two `search_id` columns - have different character sets. One has `CHARSET = latin1` and the other `CHARSET = utf8`. The types are the same `varchar(100)` but charsets differ and that matters. Columns that are used in joins or comparisons should have identical datatypes and charsets (and collations), otherwise indexes become useless.

You should either alter the charset of one of the two tables or just one of the two columns so the character sets are matching.

As @jynus has already suggested, a composite index on `(pricing_id, search_id)` should also improve the plan and the efficiency of the queries.

Comment: I tried this by creating dummy tables with the same create scripts with just "latin1" to "utf8" change and some dummy data but still getting the same problem.

Comment: @tarnisharma and you tried the queries suggested by Jynus? And with the index suggested?

Comment: yes i did. I cant change the schema anyways so even if they did work I would not have been able to get them done. But search_Criteria still did not use the index.